# How to call a tidy-up method when reference to object goes out of scope?

Tags: python, scope, reference

I'd like to get a reference to an object, where the reference will be relatively short-lived, and at the end of the life of the reference I want to release cached resources that the object will use to service that reference efficiently, rather than expecting the caller to remember to do this itself.

Searching around a bit I found things like class decorators, but that seems to be used in the opposite way from what I want.  I want to "decorate" a reference rather than the object type itself.

I also found how to delegate attributes of an object so I can create a class that presents itself as the underlying object while having an independent `__del__` method to perform clean-up.  Like so:

```
def get_wrapped_thing(id):
  class TidyUp:
    def __init__(self, obj):
      self.__dict__['obj'] = obj
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
      return getattr(self.obj, attr)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
      return setattr(self.obj, attr, value)

    def __del__(self):
      self.obj.tidyup()

  thing = get_thing(id)
  return TidyUp(thing)
```

I think that should work, but it feels like it's probably a bad way to go about things.  Too many underscores usually makes me think I'm doing it wrong.

Is there a "pythonic" way to recognise when cached resources can be cleaned up because the reference that caused their allocation has gone out of scope?

The `tidyup()` method and the resource allocation methods may be different for different objects from `get_thing()` (some of them don't need a cache) so I can't just hoist all that caching logic into the wrapper itself.

Comment: *"Is there a "pythonic" way to recognise when cached resources can be cleaned up because the reference that caused their allocation has gone out of scope?"* One would argue that the most pythonic way to achieve this is to just not to, and let Python's garbage collector do its job

Answer (score 0):

```py
import gc
del object_to_delete
gc.collect() # force-clean memory after that
```